# A phrase to describe a "collection of false exaggerations"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I am looking for a phrase to describe a "collection of false exaggerations", something that can fit well in the following line:

> I am really shocked to see this, it seems that everything you told me before was just a collection of false exaggerations.

I don't think "collection of false exaggerations" is a real phrase. "Bag of lies" is a similar phrase but not with the same meaning.

I am looking for a phrase that can directly replace mine in the above sentence or otherwise any other way to say the above sentence while keeping the feelings same. The feelings here being that my expectations were set too high due to a lot of exaggerated information fed to me.

Comment: "False exaggeration"?  Exaggerations are inaccurate by definition.  What would you consider to be a "true" exaggeration?  I think your question may be a non-starter because you are looking for a collective phrase for a nonsensical term.

Comment: *Pack of lies* seems to fit admirably -- and, perhaps, ironically, since it is itself an exaggeration.

Comment: I'm with @itsbruce. "False exaggerations" doesn't seem right.

Comment: I am sorry. That's just my bad english. We can omit the word "false". Are there any phrases for just a "collection of exaggeration" like a "Pack of lies".

Comment: @AndrewLeach Just curious, why is a Pack of lies an exaggeration.

Comment: "... a pile of exaggerations" or just "... *everything* you told me was (just) pure exaggeration." The word "before" is superfluous.

Comment: *Exaggeration* implies that there was some truth, but that it was over-embellished. "Pack of *lies*" implies there was *no* truth. So "pack of lies* is exaggerating because there was actually *some* truth. (But I'll leave @AndrewLeach to confirm whether my reasoning is the same as his.)

Comment: @TrevorD Just so :-)

Comment: What's wrong with just one word?  How about balderdash.  Have to have two words?  How about hyperbolic balderdash.  Back to one word:  bushwa.  Have to have two words?  Hyperbolic bushwa.

Answer (score 1):

The term *[hyperbole](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hyperbole)* means

> extravagant exaggeration (as “mile-high ice-cream cones”)

It does not necessarily refer to a *collection*.

You could create a phrase such as *a plethora of hyperbole*, or some such.

(Or even *a hurricane of hyperbole*.)

Comment: Since creating [ridiculously detailed and variegated collective nouns](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Collective_nouns) is one of the main fortes of the English language, one might even go a bit crazy and invent something like _a cornucopia of hyperbole_ or _a cataclysm of hyperbole_. The fact that the collective noun itself is highly hyperbolic is, of course, part of the beauty of it. :-D

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes. See addition.

Comment: Is *hyperbole* a countable noun?

Comment: @ThePhoton, I would say no. Using it in a countable way sounds unnatural to me. I just checked a couple of dictionaries, and they all have it listed as a mass noun only, too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Based on this [article](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/countable-and-uncountable-nouns/) on countable and non-countable nouns, I'd argue that *'hyperbole'* is countable. For example *'How many hyperboles were on that page?'*.

Comment: @Terah That's exactly the usage that sounds very unnatural and off to me. It sounds about as right as “How many furnitures were in the living room?” to my ears. I would say “How many instances/examples of hyperbole were on that page?”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I understand where you are coming from, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole), for example, uses '*hyperboles'* a number of times. Singular *'hyperbole'* refers to the concept of it, whereas *'hyperboles'* are the invidual instances where hyperbole was employed. EDIT: my assumptions appears to be proven valid here, on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyperbole).

Comment: @Terah It's not _that_ uncommon for a word to be count to some people and non-count to others; I guess this is one of those words.

Comment: In this case, hyperbole can simply refer to two different things, one countable, the other one uncountable. It depends more on which is used and in what context that determines whether or not it's uncountable than that it depends on who reads the word :)

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Leach comments, the standard idiom (informal, primarily spoken not written) is...

> [a **pack** of lies](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pack+of+lies) *- a completely false story, account, etc.*

Answer (score 1):

[*Tall tales*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tall_tale) are fanciful and elaborate stories, often highly exaggerated. The phrase  specifically refers to American fables that explain the natural world, but is also used by analogy to describe more mundane exaggerated stories. Or as an indirect way to say someone is lying.

A *fish story* is an exaggerated story that glorifies the teller. It refers to  boastful claims by anglers that they hooked a "big one that got away".

Answer (score 0):

You could simply replace your phrase with the following pleonasm 'exaggerated hyperbole'.