# What do you call exaggerations like "I'm starving"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

For example, when you are a little hungry and you say "I'm starving", or when you are so tired and you say "I'm dying". What do you call these type of expressions? Just exaggerations? I don't know how to explain this better.

Comment: Highly related to this question on [A phrase to describe a collection of false exaggerations](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122965/a-phrase-to-describe-a-collection-of-false-exaggerations) or even better, possible duplicate of it.

Comment: Sometimes it's just called *the Big E*, often accompanied by a hand gesture in which the right thumb and forefinger make an arc and the left forefinger bisects it (forming a rough capital E to the viewer).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is an example of [*hyperbole*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole).

Comment: that's what i was looking for

Comment: And be careful with the pronunciation.  It does not sound like "superbowl".

Comment: Way to go, Jasper. I knew you could do it.

Comment: This is the best English.SO answer ever!

Comment: @GarrettAlbright Do meta-comments belong on meta?